# bash scripting: find exact accordance with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I try to find the **exact** accordance of a word in my file with grep.

### Example:

`grep -n polkit /tmp/packages-puppy-*`

The issue:

`/tmp/packages-puppy-5:302:polkit
/tmp/packages-puppy-5:303:polkit_DEV
/tmp/packages-puppy-5:304:polkit_DOC
/tmp/packages-puppy-6:182:lxpolkit`

I'd like the issue is only:

`/tmp/packages-puppy-5:302:polkit`

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to match lines that contain nothing but the search string? If so, you can do `grep -n '^polkit$' FILES`

Comment: Or use directly `-w` as indicated in the duplicate.